# Cutting an input graph into partitions of a certain size, minimizing the weight of the edges being removed - Name?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, computational-complexity

**Input:** A weighted graph $G = (V, E)$, a maximum size $t$, a number of partitions $k$.

**Output:** $k$ partitions of $G$, represented by the partitions $P = \{p1, ..,p_n\}$ and the set of cut edges $C \subset E$ which divide $G$ into those partitions. Each partition $p$ is of size $|p| = t$, except the last partition, which is of size $|p|<t$. The weight of the edges cut ($\sum |C_i|$) should be minimised.

Is this a problem that already exists? It seems as if it could be some variation of the [k-multicut problem](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/01/kmulticut.pdf) which uses pairs $(s,t)$ that must be separated. Or perhaps it is related to the [Max-Flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem). Other things I have looked at are the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) and the [Minimum multicut](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture18.pdf), however none of these have bounds on the size of the partitions that are created.

I would also be interested in finding out the complexity class of the problem. I suspect it is NP-Hard.

Background: I am researching possible ideas for a university undergraduate project, and want to use this problem as a solution to a real world problem. If the problem is sufficiently hard it is a feasible candidate to write a lot about heuristic solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Names are *Graph Partitioning* and *Graph Clustering*.

You'll find a lot of papers about these problems, and also some software packages. I like [this](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schulz/gpgc_vorlesung/graphpartitioning_lecture.pdf) one in particular, and it's rather recent.